# Matrix conjugation gives skew transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

How to solve $MXM^{-1}=-X^t$ ?

M can be symmetric or anti-symmetric

Motivation: Given an inner product space with metric matrix M, a "rotation" matrix $R(k)$ that preserve norms can be obtained by matrix exponential $R(k)=e^{kX}$ where X is the generator matrix of the rotation.

When metric is diagonal and has same signals, the rotation is circular but when metric has opposite signals the "rotation" is hyperbolic.

I wanna find the generator for any metric matrix given.

Comment: Connection with bilinear alternate forms [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3492873/305862)

Comment: What are we allowed to assume about the metric matrix? Clearly it's invertible; is it necessarily symmetric?

Comment: Fixed: M can be symmetric or anti-symmetric, but a general solution would be cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X,M$ are of size $n \times n$.

Note that, if no further constraint is placed on $X$, then this is simply a linear system of equations. We could solve this linear system by "brute force", assuming $M$ is sufficiently small.

Note that the equation can be rewritten as
$$
MX = -X^TM \implies MX + X^TM = 0.
$$
With (column-major) [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we could rewrite this system as
$$
[(I \otimes M)  + (M^T \otimes I)K^{(n,n)}]\operatorname{vec}(X) = 0,
$$
where $I$ denotes a size-$n$ identity matrix, $\otimes$ denotes a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), and $K^{(n,n)}$ denotes a [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix).

---

For a $2 \times 2$ matrix $M$ with entries $m_{ij}$, the above equation is
$$
\left[ 
\pmatrix{
m_{11} & m_{12} & 0 & 0\\
m_{21} & m_{22} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & m_{11} & m_{12}\\
0 & 0 & m_{21} & m_{22}}
+ 
\pmatrix{m_{11} & m_{21} &0& 0\\
0 & 0& m_{11} & m_{21}\\
m_{22} &  m_{12} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0&m_{22} & m_{12}
}
\right]\pmatrix{x_{11}\\ x_{21}\\ x_{12}\\ x_{22}} = 0
$$

---

Edit: flipped minus sign into plus sign

Comment: Please, can you give an example of brute force solution of a 2x2 matrix?

Comment: I read that $AX - XA$ = vectorization, but it's $AX + X^tA$ so would it work?

Comment: It's correct, but the sign is flipped. I will change the minus to plus in the answer.