# True or False: Let $n ≥ 4$. There is an $n\times n$ matrix A such that $A^4 = 0$ and $\text{rank}(A+I_n) < 4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I don't know how to judge this and I am a beginner at linear algebra so I need an answer which explains all necessary terms.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  You are likely to get a response if you show what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: Here is the intuition behind it, nilpotent matrix is similar to strictly upper triangular matrix (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1003525/399263). When you add $I_n$ there will be all $1$ on the diagonal and this matrix cannot have rank $<4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\text{rank}(A + I_n) < 4$, then by the rank-nullity theorem it's nullity is at least $1$, i.e. there exists some non-trivial vector $v \neq 0$ such that $(A + I_n) v = 0 \implies A v = -v$. In other words, $v$ would be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $-1$. But then
$$A^4 v = A(A(A(Av))) = v \neq 0$$
But why would this lead to a contradiction? (Hint: We haven't yet used the fact that $A^4 = 0$.)

Comment: Does the contradiction mean that "A^4 can't be zero" (since "A^4 v" is not equal to 0 and v is not 0) but the description said that "A^4 is equal to zero"?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct!